# What is CPU brand (Intel or AMD or Any) on Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, intel, amd-processor

I want to host application on VM Azure but that require Intel CPU instructions.
I saw AMD type on VM when open property on "Computer Menu". I think this is compatible CPU on Azure.

What is actual CPU brand (Intel or AMD or Any) on Windows Azure?

Comment: I believe this question to be a valid question as devs are the people that initially will always be playing around with VMs and Build Servers and etc, so it stands to reason that one developer will want to seek the help of another! It also stands to reason that he/she will want to ask the board where he tends to frequent more than any of the other SE Boards. Too many trigger happy admins now!

Answer (score 1):

While CPU type is not discussed in Windows Azure Documentation anywhere because the base understanding is that when code is running in cloud, it does not have dependency on CPU instruction level. However most of the users have found out that Azure host machines are running AMD processor indeed, and discussed in Azure Forums [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurepurchasing/thread/9eb5a474-90ba-43ab-8c79-a7e0451e9dee) as well.

Comment: If you are running IaaS (VMs) then you get to choose:
https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/amd-based-memory-optimized-azure-virtual-machines-now-available-in-more-regions/

Answer (score 1):

As stated by the other answer, it is most likely AMD, however you SHOULD NOT depend on this. There are Intel servers mixed in, and there is no promise to stay on any particular brand or chipset.

Additionally, as you are virtualized away from the CPU, using CPU specific instructions may not work, even if you are physically on the right hardware.